# ASP.NET MVC shared view-Error appears though it funcions as required

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

**EDIT**

I have a shared view called `_header.cshtml` which has bootstrap modal for login and registration.

In the controller called `RegUserController.cs` i have

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult _header()
    {
        return PartialView("_header");
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult _header(RegisterTbl rt)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (IsnsEntities1 sns = new IsnsEntities1())
            {
                sns.RegisterTbls.Add(rt);
                sns.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                rt = null;
                ViewBag.Message = "successfully registered";
            }
        }
        return PartialView(rt);

    }
```

In the `_layout.cshtml` i have

```
     <header>
        @Html.Action("_header","RegUser")
    </header>
```

The code here is working in the sense that the data is inserted to the database.But i get the error
`Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.`

Also i have done validation,which is not working inside this sharedview but works if i just use a normal view.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @MaryMelody i have seen those page and followed the same way but its not working.In fact my code above is same as one of them and for other i dont know ajax

Comment: @sum1 Well you are passing the string value "RegUser" into the header partial view instead of the proper object that it requires.